# Conditionally show jQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added jQuery tooltip to my page only showing in certain condition. 
The tooltip should only show when there are 3 images inside of "#demo" div.

I passed "onClick="plusOne(id)" to my "plus-icon" button. I want the tooltip to show next to this button when the condition meets.

Because the tooltip always show up after being active (I've tried "disable", but didn't work), so I added some condition to control what message it shows. (Later I'll change some messages to empty string whenever I don't want the tooltip to be rendered.)

Here is the js:

```
let plusOne = (id) => {
  let content = $(".plus-icon").tooltip("option", "content")

  if ($("#demo").children('img').length == 0) {
    console.log("length 0");
    $(".plus-icon").tooltip("option", "content", "length 0")
  }

  if ($("#demo").children('img').length == 1) {
    console.log("length 1");
    $(".plus-icon").tooltip("option", "content", "length 1")
  }

  if ($("#demo").children('img').length == 2) {
    $(".plus-icon").on('click', function() {
      console.log("length 2");
      $(this).tooltip('enable').tooltip('open').tooltip("option", "content", "Full!")
    })
  }

  if ($("#demo").children('img').length < 3) {
    $("#demo").append($(id).clone())
  }
}
```

My problem is:

When I click "plus-icon" once, tooltip's content is "length 0", this is correct.

When clicking twice, tooltip's content is "length 1", it's correct.

When clicking three times, nothing shows up because of the "click" function inside of that block of code.

When clicking fourth times, tooltip's content is "length 1", which is WRONG. (It should be length 2).

I'll be really appreciated if someone can point out what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: SOunds like one should be removing the other click event...

Comment: could you add the html to the question?